# Determining per-territory per-opponent vulnerability in Conquer Club?

Tags: conquer-club

What's the per-opponent vulnerability of a given territory in the 
online Risk-like game http://www.conquerclub.com? Is there an existing tool that 
solves this problem, albeit in a different context? Details:

I define vulnerability(t,x) as "the minimum number of troops 
opponent x must defeat in order to reach and conquer territory t". This calculation is non-trivial when x has no troops adjacent to t.

Sample JSON input data below (hideous), with a following explanation. The goal is to take JSON data in this format, and return per-territory per-opponent vulnerability.

```
map = {"killers":[],"countries":[{"name":"Baie de Henne","xS":240,"yS":86,"xL":304,"yL":108,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[1,23],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"Port-de-Paix","xS":288,"yS":84,"xL":367,"yL":102,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[0,2,8,7],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"Ile de la Tortue","xS":317,"yS":44,"xL":404,"yL":50,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[1,4],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"Le Borgne","xS":337,"yS":78,"xL":434,"yL":96,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[4],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"Cap-Haiten","xS":408,"yS":113,"xL":519,"yL":139,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[3,2,5,9,6],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"Fort-Liberte","xS":462,"yS":126,"xL":587,"yL":156,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[4,6],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"La Victoire","xS":434,"yS":146,"xL":555,"yL":186,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[4,12,5],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"Gonaives","xS":302,"yS":119,"xL":385,"yL":146,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[1,8,9],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"Cammon","xS":346,"yS":130,"xL":440,"yL":160,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[1,7,9],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"Paul","xS":396,"yS":152,"xL":476,"yL":178,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[7,8,4,10,11],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"Desdunes","xS":369,"yS":185,"xL":470,"yL":229,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[9,11,15,16],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"Bouli","xS":421,"yS":214,"xL":535,"yL":266,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[9,10,17,13],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"Los Posos","xS":483,"yS":207,"xL":576,"yL":230,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[13,6],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"Hinche","xS":451,"yS":213,"xL":576,"yL":269,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[11,12,14],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"Roseau","xS":480,"yS":255,"xL":606,"yL":318,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[13],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"Ile de la Gonave","xS":278,"yS":250,"xL":354,"yL":311,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[16,10,19,23],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"Saint-Marc","xS":365,"yS":241,"xL":465,"yL":299,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[15,17,10],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"Monet","xS":411,"yS":279,"xL":523,"yL":346,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[16,11,19,20,18],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"La Toison","xS":453,"yS":278,"xL":577,"yL":346,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[17,20],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"Port-au-Prince","xS":395,"yS":308,"xL":503,"yL":387,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[17,20,15],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"Kenscoff","xS":432,"yS":315,"xL":549,"yL":395,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[17,19,28,29,18],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"Jeremie","xS":109,"yS":312,"xL":140,"yL":390,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[23,22],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"Les Cayes","xS":141,"yS":359,"xL":180,"yL":450,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[21,23,24],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"Pestel","xS":154,"yS":310,"xL":197,"yL":388,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[21,22,24,15,0],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"Aquin","xS":177,"yS":341,"xL":220,"yL":422,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[23,22,25],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"Cotes de Fer","xS":262,"yS":325,"xL":334,"yL":413,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[24,26,27],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"Leogane","xS":344,"yS":326,"xL":438,"yL":408,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[25,27,28],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"Bainet","xS":338,"yS":355,"xL":430,"yL":445,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[25,26,28],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"Jacmel","xS":374,"yS":341,"xL":475,"yL":428,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[29,20,26,27],"bombardments":[]},{"name":"Belle-Anse","xS":478,"yS":364,"xL":608,"yL":457,"neutral":0,"bonus":0,"borders":[28,20],"bombardments":[]}],"continents":[{"name":"Nord","bonus":4,"required":0,"territories":[0,1,2,3,4,6,5],"subcontinents":[],"overrides":[]},{"name":"Artibonite","bonus":3,"required":0,"territories":[7,8,9,10],"subcontinents":[],"overrides":[]},{"name":"Centre","bonus":2,"required":0,"territories":[11,12,13,14],"subcontinents":[],"overrides":[]},{"name":"Ouest","bonus":5,"required":0,"territories":[15,16,17,19,20,18],"subcontinents":[],"overrides":[]},{"name":"Sud","bonus":2,"required":0,"territories":[21,22,23,24],"subcontinents":[],"overrides":[]},{"name":"Sud-Est","bonus":3,"required":0,"territories":[25,26,27,28,29],"subcontinents":[],"overrides":[]}],"requirements":[],"objectives":[],"reinforcements":[],"positions":[],"title":"Haiti","large":"Haiti.L.jpg","small":"Haiti.S.jpg","widthS":"550","heightS":"407","widthL":"698","heightL":"517","min_reinforcement":0,"country_counter":30};

armies = [{"player":"4","quantity":1},{"player":"1","quantity":1},{"player":"1","quantity":1},{"player":"2","quantity":1},{"player":"2","quantity":1},{"player":"2","quantity":1},{"player":"2","quantity":1},{"player":"1","quantity":5},{"player":"4","quantity":1},{"player":"4","quantity":1},{"player":"4","quantity":1},{"player":"2","quantity":3},{"player":"2","quantity":1},{"player":"2","quantity":1},{"player":"2","quantity":1},{"player":"4","quantity":1},{"player":"4","quantity":1},{"player":"3","quantity":1},{"player":"3","quantity":1},{"player":"3","quantity":1},{"player":"3","quantity":1},{"player":"0","quantity":3},{"player":"4","quantity":1},{"player":"4","quantity":1},{"player":"4","quantity":3},{"player":"1","quantity":3},{"player":"1","quantity":1},{"player":"1","quantity":1},{"player":"3","quantity":1},{"player":"3","quantity":1}];
```

- "map =" defines the fixed map. Each entry in "countries" represents 
  a territory. For example, "Baie de Henne" is territory 0, 
  "Port-de-Paix" is territory 1, "Ile de la Tortue" is territory 2, and 
  so on.
- The "borders" field tells which territories can attack each 
  other. In more complex maps, some attacks are 1-way, but not 
  here. For this map, if s can attack t, then t can attack s.
- The "map =" line has lots more info, but nothing useful for this question.
- The "armies =" line gives the owner and number of troops for each 
  territory (changes each turn). For example, player 4 has 1 troop on 
  territory 0 (which we know from above is "Baie de Henne"), player 1 
  has 1 troop on territory 1 ("Port-de-Paix"), and player 1 also has 1 
  troop on territory 2 ("Ile de la Tortue").

  This information should be sufficient to calculate per-territory 
  per-opponent vulnerability.

**Note:** a player may not attack his own troops. Example:

- Opponent x has 1 troop on s, adjacent to t.
- Opponent x has 100 troops on r, adjacent to s, but not adjacent to t.
- The 100 troops or r cannot attack the 1 troop on s to get to t.
- On the map below, player 1 is red, 2 is green, 3 is blue, 
  and 4 is yellow. As with many conquerclub.com maps, it's not 
  trivially obvious which territories border which: that's one reason I 
  want this program.

[image: Risk map]

[This program](https://github.com/barrycarter/bcapps/blob/master/bc-conquerclub-reconstruct-game.pl#L22) (written for a completely different reason) may be 
 helpful and/or confusing.

Even if no one's written a program specifically for 
 conquerclub.com, is there a general tool that solves these kinds of 
 problem?

I realize I could use networkx, treat this as a digraph, and use 
 shortest paths, but is there something "higher level" I could use?

Comment: Darn it, now I'm going to spend the whole day tomorrow thinking about this.

Comment: Belongs on gamedev?

Comment: I think this question belongs on this site. It's just a particularly mathy/programming-related way of breaking down a game mechanic that needs to be determined.

Comment: @Mechko - this is about the mechanics behind an existing game which help the gamer do better - and not something needed for the development of any new game. All that said, barrycarter, I'm not entirely sure our website is the best place to get an answer for this type of question - good luck anyway.

Comment: Thanks. I might modify it + post it to math or programming too. But I'm pretty sure the people here are mathematicians and programmers too.

Comment: Programmers is for subjective questions...I'd go straight to StackOverflow.

Comment: The tool you're looking for would basically be combining a shortest-paths algorithm with [this question](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3514/how-can-i-estimate-my-chances-to-win-a-risk-battle) from BCG, right? If you've already written something in the same family, the answer's likely one you can post yourself once you've done it ... I'd think you'd have found a tool by now if one existed.